# How to interpret Tasseled Cap Greenness for Landsat 5?

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, ndvi

I have amassed a few promising literature articles, and looked at the help files for ENVI, ArcMap and PCI, and no one really goes into great depth on how to interpret spectral values for Tasseled Cap greenness. More specifically, what is the range of healthy vegetation in the greenness band? I know for NDVI it is 0.3-0.5. I'm getting different ranges of values according to different scenes for TC-green, so is the range scene-dependent?

Comment: Have you converted your scenes to reflectance and applied atmospheric corrections?  Are you working with Landsat 8?

Answer (score 1):

The range is somewhat scene-dependent and Jensen (2007) recommends computing the coefficients locally. This Kauth-Thomas Transformation was designed for the Landsat MSS and TM sensors. Healthy, dense vegetation will have higher values in Brightness and Greenness.

Comment: Thanks! That's along the lines of the answers I've been encountering in literature. Does the Jensen text suggest exactly how to locally compute the coefficients?

Comment: Yes, it provides the coefficients for each band that could be used to compute the values for specific scenes. Jensen's book is titled "Remote Sensing of the Environment," and is a classic RS text.